# Anaconda won't open

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda

For some reason my Anaconda stoped working. I already reinstalled it, but it just won't work.

I tried o install Pycharm, but it won't work netheir. It says "can't find interpreter"

Python IDLE is working fine, thought. I already reinstalled all 3 programs.

When I open Anaconda, it opens the cmd showing this below, and then closes.

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be added to your PATH or something low level like that?